# Swift iOS: iAd not populating

Tags: swift, iad

I'm building an iPhone app with swift, and I've got a Rectangular Banner ad I'm trying to show.  I've gotten my Dev account properly set up for iAds, but the ad doesn't populate in the app.  I get *a* test ad, but not where I expect it.

Here's the code for the controller with the ad, and a screenshot:

```
//
//  AdViewController.swift
//
//  Created by Kevin Whitaker on 3/26/15.
//

import UIKit
import iAd

class AdViewController: UIViewController, ADBannerViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var AdView: ADBannerView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        self.canDisplayBannerAds = true
        AdView = ADBannerView(adType: ADAdType.MediumRectangle)
        AdView?.delegate = self
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
        return false
    }

    // MARK: - Ads
    func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
        self.view.addSubview(banner)
    }

    func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {
        banner.removeFromSuperview()
    }

}
```

[image: Screenshot of the blank ad]

Comment: So are you asking about the actual placement of the AdView within your view controller? If that's the case then I think its controlled by where you placed it as defined in the interface builder file that has the scene for your view controller.

Comment: MediumRectangle is only used for iPad, is this an iPad app?ADAdTypeMediumRectangle
A pad-only 320x250 point ad, based on the International Advertising Bureau’s “Medium Rectangle” Interactive Marketing Unit.

Available in iOS 6.0 and later.[https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/ADBannerView_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/ADAdType]

Comment: This is an iPhone app.  I've seen ads like this in other iPhone apps (or similar ads, at least).  Is there something else I should be using?

Comment: @deanware - I'm trying to figure out why the ad (center rectangle) isn't being populated when the view controller is loaded.  It's positioned totally fine as of right now.

Comment: I think that using self.candisplaybannerads is messing things up. That line of code just shows a banner ad with nothing else you need to do. It might be interfering with your actual ad you want to display.

Comment: I would love to know if you are still running that one line of code I mentioned. Just for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @KnightOfDragon mentioned in the comments, [the medium rectangle ad is only available for applications running on iPad](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/iAdRichMediaAds.html).
What you're looking for is an [interstitial ad](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iAd/Reference/UIViewController_iAd_Additions/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/ADInterstitialPresentationPolicy). These are the full screen ads you see in other iPhone apps.